# Write text inside some shape in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, coordinates

How can i write text between some pre-defined coordinates in tikz?. As shown in the attached figure, i want to write text between a-b-c-d coordinates.[image: write text between coordinates.]

Comment: There is the `trapezium` shape from the `shapes.geometric` library, otherwise you could just add a node in the area by specifying `at (<coordinate that lies inside the polygon>)`, there’s `path picture`, there is the `barycentric cs:`, … there are many ways to find any coordinate relative to the corners. Could you try to elaborate what you mean with “between some pre-defined coordinates”?

Answer (score 2):

I have tried

```
\node at (barycentric cs:a=1,b=1,c=1,d=1) {my text};
```

and it worked.